# Voltage at netbook's earphones output.

Tags: audio, sound

Is there any standrad that specifies max voltage at earphones output in netbooks? What values can I expect, can it be 5V or rather 1,8V ? Is there any way to monitor current (current I mean adjective, not noun) Voltage for left and right channels of that output?

Comment: If you want software, take a look at sound card socilloscope programs and set them to work on stereo-mix. You'll get the shape of the waveform, but you  won't get the voltage levels.

Comment: Since my answer was deleted somehow, I'll comment instead. Yes, there is the European Norm EN50332 (http://isvr.co.uk/labtests/en50332.htm) for consumer devices which dictates that the maximum output voltage for a headphone output with detachable headphones is 150 millivolts. Also, the norm dictates that a device must calculate the accumulated sound output energy and reduce the volume after certain conditions. Mods, can you clarify why exactly this is off-topic? (feeling strange)

Comment: If I am not able to reword my question to fit the rules in the help center, should I delete it ?

Comment: @user3023499 you can't, it has an upvoted answer. Something strange is happening and it doesn't seem to be clear to anyone what's going on exactly. In my opinion this post should be moved to [su] where it may be on topic. It was moved there, and then suddenly moved back for a to me unknown reason. I'm waiting for a reply from a moderator. Sorry for all the fuzz in any case though.

Answer (score 1):

You could play the hardest sound you can and monitor the voltage with an oscilloscope (if you have one) or a multimeter measuring AC (even though it isn't really AC that will do).

The actual values may vary from netbook to netbook.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I got no oscilloscope nor multimeter. I thought rather about special program but I did not find any.

Comment: @user3023499 if you're looking for some kind of software you're unfortunately in the wrong place to ask and should ask on [su] instead. Don't worry, I flagged the post for migration already. However, I'm afraid the voltage level will be so close to the hardware that it isn't visible to the OS anymore. I'm hardly an expert though.

Comment: @CamilStaps, your chart is for line out, for headphone out the situation is different because of the (occasionally nightmarish) European Norm 50332 (http://www.isvr.co.uk/labtests/en50332.htm) which dictates that the maximum output voltage for a headphone output with detachable headphones is 150 millivolts. **I wrote an answer about this, what happened to it?** Also, the norm dictates that a device must calculate the accumulated sound output energy and reduce the volume after certain conditions.

Comment: @PkP I have over 10k rep, so I can see deleted posts. I can't see your post, so it isn't deleted in the usual way. You may want to use flag option to call for moderator attention and explain what's going on.

Comment: Something weird is happening here. The question was migrated to [su] and is back now. Maybe that has something to do with it. @PkP thanks, I didn't know that and will revise my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think I submitted the answer just as it was being migrated; I saw my answer in SU, but cannot see it back here. Well, no matter, the essential information is in the comments I wrote.

Comment: @PkP it should be the answer though. I asked Nick if he knows what's happened [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/895/ee-ask-a-moderator) and we'll see. I don't understand why it wouldn't be on topic on [su], but I'm not very familiar with that community, so perhaps it got rejected later on.

Comment: A question that asks about voltage makes no sense on superuser.  This belongs here - it's clearly *not* about a typical end-user scenario, but rather about interfacing something custom to readily available hardware, where the *electrical details* are key.

Comment: @ChrisStratton considering that OP [is looking for a program](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146891/voltage-at-netbooks-earphones-output/146892?noredirect=1#comment297591_146892) and the question actually asks about a computer standard, superuser may be more appropriated, even more now that it's clear that OP doesn't have any measurement apparatus. *This question can't be answered from an EE point of view.*

Comment: @CamilStaps - your link goes nowhere meaningful.  Further, the question can **and has already** been addressed from an EE point of view.  One can also readily determine things from the *power rating* and impedance of the devices commonly intended to be connected.  Measurement would not be preferred anyway, as it would capture only one instance, not the design norm.

Comment: Alright, you certainly got a point with the power rating. In any case, the question has been answered well by PkP so we don't need to stay on this too long. (the link goes to a comment on this page, but if it's already in your window it doesn't do anything - opening it in a new tab works).